# Backbone Stickit input value change from outside

Tags: backbone.js, input, backbone-stickit

I have a datepicker that sets a date on an input.  I am binding it with stickit.  The problem is that since the datepicker (and not a keystroke) changes the value of the input, the stickit binding doesn't observe the change.  If I enter the date manually, there is no problem.

```
bindings: {
                        'input[name=RecordDate]': {
                            observe: 'recdate',
                            onSet: 'dosome'
                        }
                    },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend adding a global handler to handle all of the datepickers across your project. The following handler will match any bound element with the class: 'jquery-datepicker':

```
Backbone.Stickit.addHandler({
    selector: '.jquery-datepicker',
    initialize: function($el, model, options) {
        $el.datepicker({
            onChangeMonthYear: function() {
                model.set(options.observe, $el.val());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here is an example fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/px6UP/29/

[More about handlers.](http://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/#custom-handlers)

Let me know if that works for you. I plan on documenting handlers better with a cookbook or examples in the near future...

Comment: Mathew, you are awesome!  I am a big fan!  Will try and let you know.

Comment: Although this obviously works, I wound up changing the datepicker to Kendo's, which triggers onSet without any additional hooks.